# Characters not getting matched by [A-Za-z]

Tags: regex, utf-16

I am trying to match all latin characters in UTF 16 encoded text. I have been using [A-Za-z] which has been working great. As I've been parsing chinese and japanese text I've been coming across bizarre versions of A-Z that the regex isn't picking up.

https://gist.github.com/kyleect/1c66fd388d362653969d

Left are the characters I can't identify, right is from my keyboard. I copy and pasted them in to chrome page find input, google search and the find input in my text editor. All agree: `Left == Right` but `Right != Left`

What are these characters and wow do I target them in regex?

Comment: Time to learn about Unicode character classes.

Comment: Which regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at their character codes in your browser’s console:

```
> 'Ｂ'.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
ff22
```

[It’s a fullwidth letter!](http://codepoints.net/U+FF22) You can probably match the whole set with `[\uff21-\uff3a]` in a decent regex engine. Or `Ａ-Ｚ` in an even more decent one.

Comment: This worked. I even started looking through a UTF16 char list a coworker sent but couldn't find it.